# Android - Getting value from another method

Tags: android, class, methods, call

I'm still a bit new to Java and went straight in Android programming so I'm a little bit confused in some programming practices.. I just want to ask how can I call this method from another class to my OnCreate()? My method is in DBFunctions.java. Basically, I will use this in my game's options.

```
public void checkExistence(Cursor check) {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM option WHERE id = 1";
    check = db.rawQuery(sql, null);`
}
```

I want to call this in my OnCreate(). If value exists, I just want first to display "Value exists", else "No Value exists". Please also correct me if the cursor inside the parameter is right..

Answer (score 1):

Create an instance of `DBFunctions` and then call `checkExistence()`. For example:

```
DBFunctions dbfunc = new DBFunctions();
    if (dbfunc.checkExistence()) {
        /* do something */
    } else {
       /* do something else */
    }
```

So change your `checkExistence()` signature: return a boolean and Cursor should be a local variable in your method:

```
public boolean checkExistence() {
    boolean exists = false;
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM option WHERE id = 1";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
    exists =  (cursor.getCount() > 0);
    cursor.close();
    return exists;
}
```

Another option is add the `static` modifier to `checkExistence()` and call it as follows:

```
if (DBFunctions.checkExistence()) {
    /* do something */
} else {
   /* do something else */
}
```

Comment: It always force closes. At first, I think it can't handle empty tables so I add a data then try again but it still closes.. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: @PhilipSy Did you open your database before calling `checkExistence()`?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should declare the Cursor as a local variable in your method. After you obtain the Cursor check if the value exists and return a boolean. The method prototype should look like:

```
public boolean checkExistence()
```

From the onCreate method you will call this as follows:

```
if (new DBFunctions().checkExistence()) {
    // do something
} else {
   // do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call any method that is been other class you can call it by reference to its class name like below:::(Make that function static)

ClassName.FunctionName() thats all....

even you can return value from your function just instead if void use your return type...

Comment: In my case, It should return a value.. whenever my app will start, it will check the option table. How should I do that in my OnCreate()?

Comment: that value is string or boolean

Answer (score 0):

To call this method from another class, you first have to create an instance of the `DBFunctions`. Then the syntax for this method call would look something like this:

```
Cursor mycursor = ...;

DBFunctions myFunctions = new DBFunctions();
myFunctions.checkExistence(mycursor);
```

Alternatively, if you would like to avoid creating an instance of `DBFunctions`, you can add the static keyword to your method declaration, such as:

```
public static void checkExistence(Cursor check) {
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM option WHERE id = 1";
    check = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
}
```

You can then call the static method without a `DBFunctions` instance:

```
DBFunctions.checkExistence(mycursor);
```

Comment: Can i just put a null when declaring mycursor in onCreate()?

Comment: I already put null in mycursor but it still force closes.. What value will i put in it?

Comment: You need to instantiate it by calling a constructor, or get it by other means. Read over the Cursor documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) to get a grasp on how it works. As for using null - as long as you aren't making calls from `check`, it should work. You are probably getting a `NullPointerException` after this method is called.